# jQuery load() function is behaving weirdly

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to set the height of the parent element equal to the height of the child element, which is an image. For this, I am using the following code:

HTML

```
<section class="first">
    <div class="slidercontainer">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image1" class="image1">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image2" class="image2">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image3" class="image3">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image4" class="image4">
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.first{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.first .slidercontainer{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    //border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
}

.first .slidercontainer img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.image1{
    left: 0px;
}

.image2{
    left: 100%;
}

.image3{
    left: 200%;
}

.image4{
    left: 300%;
}
```

jQuery

```
var sliderImage = $(".first .slidercontainer img:nth-child(1)");
$(sliderImage).load(function(){
    var sliderHeight = sliderImage.height();
    $(".slidercontainer").height(sliderHeight);
});
```

I am using the `load()` function as the height of `.slidercontainer` can be set only after `.image1` has been loaded.

This *almost* works fine. The problem I am having is that the height of `.slidercontainer` is always set **9px more than** the height of the `.image1`. What could be a reason for this?

If this is relevant : I am using the same code for the `resize()` function. It works perfectly fine there. So when I reload the page, and then resize it, the extra 9px is gone.

Comment: does `.slidercontainer` have padding?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani No. And, I have added the relevant CSS :)

Comment: Create a demo in a sandbox site that reproduces the problem

Comment: @charlietfl I am somehow not being able to replicate the problem on jsfiddle. I am on it, though.

Comment: Hard to help when we can't reproduce

Comment: @charlietfl This is similar. https://jsfiddle.net/ag_dhruv/dLLj86fL/10/ Please run this when the console is open to view my problem. It somehow works fine when the console is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give size using .css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".slidercontainer img").each(function(){

        $(this).on('load',function(){
            $height=$(this).height();
            $(".slidercontainer").css('height',$height);
        });
        //alert($height);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add box-sizing property to your .slidercontainer css

```
.first .slidercontainer{
    .....
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

let me know if this can help you ;)

Comment: That didn't help :( Actually, I realized that the JS code mentioned in the question is causing my `$(window).width()` to reduce by 9px. And I have no idea why that's happening. Maybe you could help?

Comment: Is it always additional 9px on all browsers? Do you have any link to this html page? I will help you check it :)